# The privacy-focused Decentraleyes extension for Chrome and Firefox is supposed to emulate CDNs, but what are they really?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, cdn

After reading the wiki for the privacy-focused Decentraleyes extension available for both the Chrome and Firefox browsers, I am still confused on what the extension does. According to said wiki, Decentraleyes works by emulating CDNs by serving common files locally, but what are CDNs? I understand that there are a number of CDNs providers out there, including Cloudflare, which not only help reduce latency but also do things like DDoS protection.

More specifically, if I also have the NoScript extension installed, how come leaving the cdnjs.cloudflare.com script blocked by default in the NoScript extension (a popular security extension) results in a functional site on some sites whereas on other sites you have to allow it in order to get a functional site? Don't websites typically use Cloudflare to hide the entire website behind their CDN to lower latency? And if I leave cdnjs.cloudflare.com blocked in NoScript, how come some websites are still accessible? Or is cdnjs.cloudflare.com only for JavaScript libraries, and not for hiding entire websites?

I'm just trying to understand what a CDN does. Is the term "CDN" really just a generic term for any general technology that allows websites to lower latency for any type of resource?

Comment: Did you look for explanations of what a CDN is online? Did you seek to see the parallels between CDNs and what these plugins do?

Comment: Yes, I think my question shows that. CDNs lower latency by sitting closer to client computers allowing clients to load webpages faster. Still, I'm not sure if I quite understand what a cdnjs.cloudflare.com is doing? Could you explain to me why blocking cdnjs.cloudflare.com on some sites using NoScript doesn't block the entire website? Basically, what I'm trying to figure out is whether the Decentraleyes extension is a useful extension to have. I've been using it for weeks but I don't see its counter incrementing, except when I use this site. When I allow cdnjs.cloudflare.com why isn't...

Comment: ...it incrementing. I like to keep the number of extensions to a minimum and am reluctant to install a lesser-known extension that could make me more vulnerable to browser fingerprinting. If I allow cdnjs.cloudflare.com in NoScript and the Decentraleyes counter doesn't get incremented, does that mean the website is self-hosting its JavaScript libraries or does it mean the website is just using a lesser-known JavaScript libraries that just doesn't come bundled in Decentraleyes?

Comment: "js" means Javascript, so CDNJS is the CDN for scripts, from an educated guess. Blocking a script isn't blocking the entire site. It's as simple as that.

Comment: OK, but if CDNJS is for JavaScript libraries, then why isn't the Decentraleyes counter incrementing whenever a JavaScript library is requested? According to the wiki, Decentraleyes should be intercepting requests for common JavaScript libraries and serving those libraries locally. Do most websites just not rely on external CDNs for their JavaScript libraries? Sorry but I'm not a web developer, I don't understand how websites are typically designed.

Comment: Your website can use scripts from cdnjs.cloudflare.com without having Cloudflare's middleman between the origin server and the client, and you can proxy your site on Cloudflare without having to use CDNJS.